# Fast Fourier Transform algorithm implementation with MapReduce

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, fft

I want to implement a **Fast Fourier Transform** algorithm with **MapReduce**. I know of a recursive-FFT algorithm but I need your guideline in order to implement it using a Map/Reduce approach.

Any suggestions/references?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fft algorithm implementation with hadoop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983982/fft-algorithm-implementation-with-hadoop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea that we can use some theorems to divide problem into subproblems.

In case of Fourier Transfom, problem is standard definition of FT:

[image]

After applying [Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) we can split it to two subproblems:

[image]

Moving forward with that transfomation, theoretically it could be solved with parallel programming.

Maybe, you'll find following links useful:

- [Schönhage-Strassen Algorithm with MapReduce
  for Multiplying Terabit Integers](http://people.apache.org/~szetszwo/ssmr20110430.pdf)
- [FFT with MapReduce](http://blog.jierenchen.com/2010/08/fft-with-mapreduce.html)

Comment: The second link is broken - please amend or remove it.